# I need SDK for fingerprint virdi and sample to view how can I read thumb and verification it?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, activex

I have web application based on .net v4.0 and i need add new feature for it,
I want to allow the users access to the system by enter your thumb on fingerprint virdi machine.

I need steps or sample to view how i can do it.

Answer (score 6):

In this link, you can find UCBioBSP SDK and UCS SDK:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B06Dxl8hzdKDZllHYlloU3lZbUk&usp=sharing

The examples can be found in the folder below, after installing the files:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\UnionCommunity\UCBioBSP SDK\"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\UnionCommunity\UCS SDK v4.0\"

The SDK provide source code in C#, VB and C++

tags: (VIRDI source code, VIRDI code examples, UNIONCOMM)

Comment: Please remember links disappear, sometimes, it is better to have the essence of it in your answer

Comment: hi thank you for your answer but i cant download this file "Delphi - UCSAPI (StartServer-OK).v2.rar" , how can download it?